# removing \n from a string retrieved from DB

Tags: php

I have tried quite a few things so far with no luck:

I am using TinyMCE, which I run through mysql_real_escape_string() then add to database.

heres an example of the string thats stored in the DB:

`<p>It would be nice to be able to put this in 2 categories....</p>\n<p>something to think about.</p>`

I retrieve the data then I get problems.  I can't get rid of the \n

$string = the database entry listed above

```
$string = substr($item['body'], 0, 120). "...";
$item['bodysum'] = nl2br(stripslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br />", $string)));
```

Here is a pic of the output.

[image]

I just want it to be normal HTML.  If possible I'd like to convert it all to one line as well instead of making the section larger.  Its supposed to be a summary of what someone posts, so having it make the summary area larger for 1 word then a new line doesn't make sense!

Comment: One thing - you do not need to `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` for the HTML code, leave it as is on one row, it's ok and do not impact performance, in fact, it's faster and lighter.

Comment: I think you might have that backwards. Try `$item['bodysum'] = nl2br(stripslashes(str_replace("\n", "<br />", $item)));` - see what that does. Or, `$item['bodysum'] = nl2br(stripslashes(str_replace("\n", "", $item)));`

Comment: @fred didn't seem to work. still getting the same output with the 'n' floating there

Comment: @RickyMason Try `preg_replace` instead, see what that does. They are 2 different "animals" altogether.

Comment: @RickyMason Or try `$item['bodysum'] = (str_replace("\n", "<br />", $string));` - just to test without the extra parts.

Comment: This is the HTML its putting on the page `<div class="tl-body"><p>It would be nice to be able to put this in 2 categories....</p>n<p>something to think about.</p></div>`

Comment: @RickyMason **Q:** - How is the `\n` initially inserted from?

Comment: @RickyMason Then try this: `$item['bodysum'] = nl2br(stripslashes(str_replace("</p>n<p>", "</p><p>", $item)));` - I'm guessing here that it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that "\n" a literal "\" followed by "n"? If that's the case, then try:

```
$item['bodysum'] = nl2br(str_replace("\\n", "<br />", $string));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first **strip_slashes** than **nl2br**

```
$item['bodysum'] = nl2br(stripslashes($string));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$text = '<p>It would be nice to be able to put this in 2 categories....</p>\n<p>something to think about.</p>';

echo preg_replace('#(\\\r|\\\r\\\n|\\\n)#', '<br/>', $text);
```

[EXAMPLE HERE](https://eval.in/34319)